# "paid a winking homage to~"

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [a *New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/18/arts/music/dad-rock.html).

> As I’ve been making peace with my own appreciation for dad rock, I’ve
> noticed some contemporary female musicians doing the same — albeit
> with their own irreverent twists. In 2018, when the all-female trio
> boygenius released its debut EP, its cover art paid a **winking**
> homage to Crosby, Stills & Nash’s first album.

I wonder what the meaning of 'winking' in bold is.

Comment: It's worth saying that in the article, “homage” is linked to a [tweet that shows the comparison](https://twitter.com/kevinoconnornba/status/1031954614751350784).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Paying homage" means to show respect.  One way to pay homage in art is to respectfully copy or be influenced by an earlier artist.

"Winking" implies a cheeky or ironic mood, or it can indicate a shared secret.  So this means that the cover art copies Crosby Stills & Nash's first album, in a way that is cheeky or ironic, but is intended to show respect.  Or it might mean that the copy is an open secret - it's not obvious but it is clear if you know what to look for.